# How to target dialog buttons/Add ids

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog. I want one button to be disabled and then later enabled. I plan to do this by adding an id to the button and then using that id to use the add/remove attribute disabled. If there is another way I am open to suggestions. Here is some sample code:

```
$('#navDialog').dialog({
        modal:true,
        autoOpen:false,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        title: "Category Editor",
        buttons: {
            "Delete": function(){somethingMore();},
            "Edit": function(){something();},
            "Confirm":function(){importantSomething();}
        },
        draggable: true,
        resizable: false
    });
```

I want to be able to control the Confirm button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#navDialog').dialog({
    modal:true,
    autoOpen:false,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    title: "Category Editor",
    buttons: [{
        id:"btn-delete",
        text:"Delete",
        click:function(){somethingMore();}
    },{
        id: "btn-edit",
        text:"Edit", 
        click: function(){something();}     
   },{
        id:"btn-confirm"
        text:"Confirm", 
        click:function(){importantSomething();}
    }],
    draggable: true,
    resizable: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains(Ok)').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't any proper way of doing this. It's on the roadmap for inclusion but I don't exactly know when. I'll report back when I've found the forum post detailing this issue.

Comment: Hmm, couldn't find any. Anyone know how I can delete my own answer :p ?